# Russian symbols in re (Python)

Tags: python, regex, utf-8

I get a data from a file:

```
words = re.findall(r'[\w]+',self._from.encode('utf8'),re.U)
```

If the file contains:

> *Hi, how are you?*

Then result will be:

> ['Hi', 'how', 'are', 'you']

But if the file contains russian language (i.e. cyrillic symbols), then:

> *Привет, как дела?*

In this case the result is:

> ['\xd0', '\xd1', '\xd0', '\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1', '\xd0\xba\xd0',
>   '\xd0\xba', '\xd0', '\xd0\xb5\xd0', '\xd0']

why? wtf?
I've already added:

```
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

I'm using python2.7 and linux ubuntu.

### **Answer:**

```
words = re.findall(r'[\w]+',self._from.decode('utf8'),re.U)
print u" ".join(words)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use `\w+` to match alphanumeric *unicode* characters you should pass *both* a `unicode` pattern and `unicode` text to `re.findall`.

- In Python2:

  Assuming that you are reading bytes (not text) from the file, you should decode the bytes to obtain a `unicode`:

  ```
  uni = 'Привет, как дела?'.decode('utf-8')
  ```

  `ur'(?u)\w+'` is a [raw unicode literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640/190597).
  Even though it is not necessary here, using raw unicode/string literals for
  regex patterns is generally a good practice -- it allows you to avoid the
  need for double backslashes before certain characters such as `\s`.

  The regex pattern `ur'(?u)\w+'` [bakes-in the Unicode flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) which tells `re.findall` to make `\w` dependent on the Unicode character properties database.

  ```
  import re
  uni = 'Привет, как дела?'.decode('utf-8')
  print(re.findall(ur'(?u)\w+', uni))
  ```

  yields a list containing the 3 unicode "words":

  ```
  [u'\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442',
   u'\u043a\u0430\u043a',
   u'\u0434\u0435\u043b\u0430']
  ```
- In Python3:

  The general principle is the same, except that [what were `unicode`s in
  Python2 are now `str`s in Python3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit), and there is no longer any attempt at
  automatic conversion between the two.  So, again assuming that you are
  reading bytes (not text) from the file, you should decode the bytes to
  obtain a `str`, and use a `str` regex pattern:

  ```
  import re
  uni = b'\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82, \xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba \xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0?'.decode('utf')
  print(re.findall(r'(?u)\w+', uni))
  ```

  yields

  ```
  ['Привет', 'как', 'дела']
  ```

Answer (score 4):

My solution:

```
txt = re.findall(r'[А-я]+', data)
```

А-я - Russian alphabet letters

Answer (score 2):

Consult UTF Cyrillic block to define regex precisely:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_(Unicode_block)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode

Most codepoints are in a range, but some are not:

```py
re.compile('[А-Яа-яЁё]+')

re.fullmatch("[А-Яа-яЁё ]+", "Ёжик в тумане")
```

Also you might want to include `Ѣ ѣ` (Ять) or other old symbols depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

you are taking a string that is already unicode and encoding it as unicode
if you omit the encoding part you get:

```
line = u"Привет, как дела?"
words = re.findall(r'[\w]+',line ,re.U)
# words = [u'\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442', u'\u043a\u0430\u043a', u'\u0434\u0435\u043b\u0430']
print words[0]
# prints Привет
```

Answer (score 1):

Russian alphabet solution with Ё letter (it is not included in А-Я range)

```
import re

text = 'Ё-моё Привет! 2121 как дела?'

re.findall(r'[А-яЁё]+', text)
# => ['Ё', 'моё', 'Привет', 'как', 'дела']
```

Answer (score 0):

If `self._from` is an `unicode` string, you should pass it directly to `re.findall` (with the `re.U` flag). If it's an utf8-encoded `str` string, you need to `decode` it into an `unicode` string. You shouldn't pass non-ascii `str` strings to `re`.